# How to load android resources from server?

Tags: android, xml, resources

Hi I am working with android. I had created an android library project.Now I want to convert it to the jar file.My project contains resources so Its not possible to convert to jar file I think. So I am looking to load the resource files like xml,images etc from the server.is it possible?? How can I load the resource file like xml from the server ?? Please help me, thanks in advance :)